# Not sure if i should invoke a cast or do somethiing to the parameters

Tags: c, pointers, parameters, void

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{ 
    double dMinimum;
    double dMaximum;
    char szName[] = "Armvad Ezikon";
    double dScoreM[] =  { 40, 0, 30, 55, 0, 25 };
    int iScoreCount = 6; 
    determineMinMax(dScoreM, iScoreCount , &dMinimum, &dMaximum);
    printf("For %s, minimum = %lf and maximum = %lf ", szName, dMinimum, dMaximum);
    return 0;
}
void determineMinMax( double  dScoreM[] ,  int  iScoreCount ,  double *pdMin, double *pdMax) 
{
    int i;
    *pdMin = 200.0;  // arbitrary high value
    *pdMax = 0.0;
    for(i = 0; i < iScoreCount; i++)
    {
        if(dScoreM[i] < *pdMin)
            *pdMin = dScoreM[i];
        if(dScoreM[i] > *pdMax)
            *pdMax = dScoreM[i];
    }
}
```

When I  try to compile I get this error is it because I am not casting correctly?

exampleone.c:13:6: warning: conflicting types for ‘determineMinMax’ [enabled by default]

void determineMinMax( double  dScoreM[] ,  int  iScoreCount ,  double *pdMin,
      ^
exampleone.c:9:1: note: previous implicit declaration of ‘determineMinMax’ was here
 determineMinMax(dScoreM, iScoreCount , &dMinimum, &dMaximum);

Comment: You need a function prototype before main.

Comment: Aside, you could initialise `*pdMin` and `*pdMax` from the first element `dScoreM[0]`, to save guessing, and then iterate `i` from `1`.

Answer (score 3):

You have to put the declaration before using it  :

```
void determineMinMax( double  dScoreM[] ,  int  iScoreCount ,  double *pdMin, double *pdMax);
int main(void){
  ..
}
```

Or simply,

```
void determineMinMax( double  dScoreM[] ,  int  iScoreCount ,  double *pdMin, double *pdMax){

 ...

}

int main(void){
  ...
}
```

Otherwise it is conflicting with the implicit declaration assumed by the compiler which is `int determineMinMax()`. But in C99,C11 this is an error.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

void determineMinMax (double dScoreM[], int, double*, double*);

int main(int argc, const char*argv[])
{ 
    double dMinimum,dMaximum;
    char szName[] = "Armvad Ezikon";
    double dScoreM[] =  { 40, 0, 30, 55, 0, 25 };
    int iScoreCount = 6; 
    determineMinMax(dScoreM, iScoreCount , &dMinimum, &dMaximum);
    printf("For %s, minimum = %lf and maximum = %lf ", szName, dMinimum, dMaximum);
    return 0;
}

void determineMinMax ( double  dScoreM[] ,  int  iScoreCount ,  double *pdMin, double *pdMax) 
{
    int i;
    //initialize *pdMin and *pdMax with the first element of the array, just an assumption.
    *pdMin = 40; 
    *pdMax = 40;
    //You can use the following way also for initialization.
    //*pdMin = (INT_MAX); 
    //*pdMax = -(INT_MAX);
    for(i = 0; i < iScoreCount; i++)
    {
        if(dScoreM[i] < *pdMin)
            *pdMin = dScoreM[i];
        if(dScoreM[i] > *pdMax)
            *pdMax = dScoreM[i];
    }
}
```

The above code will resolve your issue, and according to C99 and C11, you need to first declare the signature/prototype of the function and then define that function, or you need to define the function before calling it from the `main()` function.

The signature tells the compiler in this case, that I have declared the function name `determineMinMax` which will take four arguments as input and return `void` means nothing, to the function from where it is called, which in your case is `main()`.

Answer (score 0):

You get the warning because you did not forward-declare the function `determineMinMax`, and you called it in `main`. The compiler assumes it has a return type of int, and that it accepts any number of parameters, which makes its prototype looks like: `int determineMinMax();`

That is why, the compiler warns you about conflicting types, because the signature of the function assumed by the compiler is different from the signature of your function.

To resolve the issue, simply include a prototype of the function before `main`:

```
void determineMinMax(double  dScoreM[], int  iScoreCount, double *pdMin, double *pdMax);

int main(void) {
...
}

void determineMinMax(double  dScoreM[], int  iScoreCount, double *pdMin, double *pdMax)
{
 ....
}
```